# NRPE script for monitoring memory usage

Tags: bash, linux, shell, plugin, status-monitoring

This script based on previous [NRPE script for monitoring load average](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/226101/nrpe-script-for-monitoring-load-average). Same purpouse - get NRPE friendly output with minimal usage of non built in commands. In this case wasn't need to count with floating point. So I could omit `bc`.

Yes, I read [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) And there is a lot of true. Bud I am still thinking about these NRPE scripts as about bash scripting trainnig to get more practice.

Desired output:

**MEMORY_TOTAL=2041316kB MEMORY_AVAILABLE=1049260kB | MEMORY_IN_PERCENTAGE=51;80;90**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -o errexit -o pipefail

warning=80
critical=90


while read -a meminfo_row; do
  # Remove the colon character. 
  row_value_lenght=$(( ${#meminfo_row[0]} -1 ))
  row_value=${meminfo_row[0]:0:$row_value_lenght}

  case $row_value in
    MemTotal)
      mem_total=${meminfo_row[1]}
      mem_apercent=$(( meminfo_row[1] / 100 ))
    ;;
    MemAvailable)
      mem_available=${meminfo_row[1]}
    ;;
  esac
done < /proc/meminfo


mem_percentage=$(( mem_available / mem_apercent ))


if [[ -z $mem_percentage ]]; then
  returned_text="MEMORY UNKNOWN - check script"
  returned_code=3
else
  returned_text="MEMORY_TOTAL=${mem_total}kB MEMORY_AVAILABLE=${mem_available}kB | MEMORY_IN_PERCENTAGE=$mem_percentage;$warning;$critical"
  if [[ $mem_percentage -gt $critical ]]; then
    returned_code=2
  elif [[ $mem_percentage -gt $warning ]]; then
    returned_code=1
  else
    returned_code=0
  fi
fi

echo "$returned_text" 
exit $returned_code
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand why it should be a warning to have over 80% of the system RAM available.  If anything needs a warning, it should be having under 20% of RAM available, right?

Reading each line into an array is overcomplicated.  The `read` builtin command is quite good at splitting each line of input into multiple variables.  (`row_value_lenght` is misspelled, by the way.)

The [proc(5) man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) says about `/proc/meminfo`:

> Each line of the file consists of a parameter name, followed by a colon, the value of the parameter, and an option unit of measurement (e.g., "kB").

There's no guarantee that the unit will be `kB` (as you have assumed in your printout), or that both lines of interest will have the same units.

Splitting up the calculation of `mem_percentage` is weird.

The `echo` statement should be line-wrapped for readability.

The cases for exit codes 0, 1 and 2 can be collapsed into one, using arithmetic.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -o errexit -o pipefail

warning=80
critical=90

while read -r label number unit ; do
    case "$label" in
      MemTotal:)
        mem_total=$number
        mem_total_unit=$unit
        ;;
      MemAvailable:)
        mem_avail=$number
        mem_avail_unit=$unit
        ;;
    esac
done < /proc/meminfo

if [ -z "$mem_avail" -o "$mem_avail_unit" != "$mem_total_unit" ]; then
    echo "MEMORY UNKNWOWN - check script"
    exit 3
fi

mem_avail_percent=$(( 100 * $mem_avail / $mem_total ))
echo "MEMORY_TOTAL=$mem_total$mem_total_unit" \
     "MEMORY_AVAILABLE=$mem_avail$mem_avail_unit" \
     "|" \
     "MEMORY_IN_PERCENTAGE=$mem_avail_percent;$warning;$critical"
exit $(( ($mem_avail_percent > $warning) + ($mem_avail_percent > $critical) ))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the great tips. I just turned aritmetic operation as: `warning="20"; critical="10"; mem_avail_percent="5"; echo $(( $mem_avail_percent < $warning) + ($mem_avail_percent < $critical) ))` = 2. I really like that.